# Is there a more specific name for uncount nouns such as: ‘furniture’, ‘equipment’, ‘luggage’, etc.?

Tags: terminology, uncountable-nouns

The following nouns belong to a distinct type in that they are uncountable no matter the context:

> baggage, bedlinen, clothing, cutlery, equipment, footwear, furniture, jewellery, luggage, machinery, tableware, underwear,

These nouns "denote **a heterogeneous aggregate of parts**," according to CGEL by Pullum.

Is there any particular name for these nouns?

### EDIT

Neither "non-count noun" (aka, "uncountable noun") nor "mass noun" is what I'm looking for, because these terms are not specific enough to pinpoint the aforementioned category.

For example, any noun that is not countable is called "non-count noun", including abstract nouns such as "bravery" and material nouns such as "water". But neither "bravery" nor "water" denotes a heterogeneous aggregate of parts.

"Mass noun" is either equivalent to "non-count noun" or to "material noun" depending on grammar.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69916/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-is-there-a-more-specific-name-for-uncount-nouns-su).

Comment: Use comments only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Other types of comment can be made in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or the [chatroom created for the purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69916).

Answer (score 4):

The uncountable nouns, listed in the OP's question, are names for groups or collections of *things*.

The noun *cutlery* (in the US *[flatware](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flatware)*) is usually singular and includes different items; knife, fork, spoon, teaspoon, etc. All of the aforementioned belong to the category of cutlery, taken individually they are countable: *I bought two new knives and a fork* (Yes), but we do not say  *I bought three new cutleries* (No) even if the items ‘knife‘ and ‘fork‘ belong to a group called “cutlery”.

There doesn't appear to be a specific name for this special type of *[collective noun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/about-nouns/nouns-singular-and-plural)*, a noun that is *normally* singular but encapsulates items that are normally countable. For example, although *team* is a collective noun, it is also countable, we can say “a team” and “several teams”. The same is not true for the noun *money*, the following sentences are considered ungrammatical (i) [*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Generative_linguistics)“she has a money” and (ii) *“she has several monies”. Although Wikipedia's article on *[mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)* distinguishes two different mass nouns, amorphous/nonsolid substances vs. objects, they fail to mention if either one has a specific name in linguistics.

> In English (and in many other languages), there is a tendency for nouns referring to liquids (water, juice), powders (sugar, sand), or substances (metal, wood) to be used in mass syntax, and for nouns referring to objects or people to be count nouns. This is not a hard-and-fast rule, however; **mass nouns such as *furniture* and *cutlery*, which represent more easily quantified objects**, show that the mass/count distinction should be thought of as a property of the terms themselves, rather than as a property of their referents. For example, the same set of chairs can be referred to as "seven chairs" and as "furniture"; although both *chair* and *furniture* are referring to the same thing, the former is a count noun and the latter a mass noun

Thus the OP will have to create their own terminology, if professor Pallum can…

I'd call them “uncountable nouns that consist of countable units” which is long-winded but comprehensible. Otherwise,

> **uncount nouns with [discrete subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)**, or, **collective mass nouns**

For more information on the fascinating land of uncountable nouns see the following pdf files.

1. *Mass counts in World Englishes: A corpus
   linguistic study of noun countability in
   non-native varieties of English* ([link](http://www.humanities.mcmaster.ca/~vickup/Schmidtke-Kuperman-CLLT-2016.pdf))
2. *[Mass Terms](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6ff5/9666bb2da38ec85849478efa4b4fff7dc580.pdf)* by Francis Jeffry Pelletier, University of Alberta
3. [MASS EXPRESSIONS](https://cs.rochester.edu/~schubert/papers/mass-expressions03.pdf) (95 pages) by Francis Jeffry Pelletier and Lenhartk. Schubert

### UPDATE

> *[Plural mass nouns and the compositionality of number](http://irserver.ucd.ie/bitstream/handle/10197/3898/verbum.pdf?sequence=1)*
>   <sub>Paolo Acquaviva, University College Dublin</sub>
>
> […] mass terms also include nouns like footwear or furniture, which
>   undoubtedly have minimal parts (a splinter or a table leg are not furniture). Reference to collections of discrete elements links plurals like *books* to this latter class of mass terms, [e.g. *furniture*] which have been called **collective masses** (Link 1998, 214, Bunt 1985, 304); this is where the similarities of count plurals and mass terms end.

elsewhere…

> **Uncountable collective nouns**, such as "furniture" and "traffic", always denote diverse multiforms. The diversity results from abstraction of the basic level. What makes these words different from the **type** set nouns such as “threat” is that they also imply multiplicity of these diverse things

[Source](http://vossen.info/docs/Thesis/Thesis%20Vossen%205%20-%20Individuation.pdf), p.204, 1995. Author: Piek Th.J.M. Vossen ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piek_Vossen))

Comment: I don't know why the Wikipedia used the word 'easily quantified objects' when even "water" can be easily quantified. So, I don't know how "quantifiable mass noun" excludes things like "water", "sugar", "metal", etc.

Comment: "Uncount nouns with discrete subsets" is rather mouthful.

Comment: JK2 could you look again at your *sugar* example? Does sugar come in grains or piles, unless people interfere to create lumps?

Can *piles* or *heaps* be counted as more than one if they’re overlapping?

Can *grains* be counted as one together, even if they’re stacked on top of each other?

Can *lumps* really be compared to either *heaps* or *grains*?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin if I have a vessel that is partially filled with water and I add more water , it is still "water", it doesn't become ten waters, likewise for sugar methinks. A pile of sugar, with added sugar piled on top, is still an unquantifiable mass, it's still "sugar". But if I have one packet/lump of sugar, and I add another packet/lump I have two packets/lumps. We don't normally count the grains of sugar, not normally... but if we do see a single grain we can identify it as such.

Comment: Yes, Mari-Lou… of course. How could it be otherwise?

Please go back and consider the difference among grains, piles and lumps…