# Is it really correct to say that some nouns are countable and others are uncountable?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, noun-phrases

It is generally accepted practice in linguistics that common nouns are classified into count nouns (aka, countable nouns) and non-count nouns (aka, uncountable nouns or mass nouns).

For example, in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 334) says:

> As the terms indicate, **count** nouns denote entities that can be counted, while **non-count** nouns denote entities that cannot be counted:
>
> [2] i *We need another **plate**.* [count]
>
> ii *We need some more **crockery**.* [non-count]

In [2], however, it is not the count noun ***plate*** itself but the whole noun phrase *another **plate*** that denotes an "entity". Similarly, it is not the non-count noun ***crockery*** itself but the whole noun phrase *some more **crockery*** that denotes an "entity" (or a collection of entities). This is because a common noun by definition does not denote an entity but only a class of entities, as shown in the following dictionary definition of the word:

A common noun is defined in [this Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/common_noun) as:

> A noun denoting a class of objects or a concept as opposed to a particular individual.

When a common noun denotes a "class", how can a common noun denote an "entity", let alone "an entity that can be counted or that cannot be counted"?

Here are clear examples that ***plate*** or ***crockery*** itself does not denote an "entity":

> [2] iii *We need some kind of **plate**.*
>
> iv *We need some more items of **crockery**.*

It's clear here that the common nouns ***plate*** and ***crockery*** do not denote entities, and that all they denote is a class of entities.

Given the analysis above, is it really correct to say that some nouns are countable and others are uncountable?

Comment: And if you add an example like "we need two plates and more crockery"? You don't see a distinction between a noun that has a normal plural (plates) and one that doesn't (crockery)? A lot of words can be used as both types, of course (I drink beer, versus right now I'm drinking _a_ beer).

Comment: @oerkelens In each of your 'beer' examples, what does the noun 'beer' itself denote?

Comment: Even assuming that a common noun can only denote a class of entity, isn't it still reasonable to say that the terms "countable noun" and "uncountable noun" mean that the entities in the classes in question can or cannot be counted? How does a sentence like "I own eight plates" fit into your point about noun phrases denoting entities?

Comment: @nnnnnn If my analysis is correct, the countability is not an attribute of a noun itself but of a noun phrase. In "I own eight plates", the noun "plate" does not refer to an entity that's countable. the NP "eight plates" refer to the entities that are countable.

Comment: My 2 cents to this discussion: count / non-count considers the "normal" usage of the noun and not the usages under a figure of speech such as metonymy; you can always have more of something that is non-count, even if you're not able to come up with exact figures, you know when there is more or less of something uncountable (like love, hate, sadness and other emotions)

Comment: @oerkelens In  "we need two plates and more crockery", "two plates" and "more crockery" are noun phrases that denote entities that are countable and uncountable, respectively. The plural form of the noun 'plate' (i.e., _plates_) is not by itself a noun, because a noun (common noun) is defined as a class, which _plates_ is not, if we are to take the Oxford definition seriously.

Comment: An entity is a thing. Beyond thar, you need Plato, Kant, etc., and need to move this to philosophy.

Comment: Related: [Is there a more specific name for uncount nouns such as: ‘furniture’, ‘equipment’, ‘luggage’, etc.?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421218/is-there-a-more-specific-name-for-uncount-nouns-such-as-furniture-equipment)

Comment: In answer to the title "Yes". Think of the word *chicken*, it can refer to the meat (U) or the carcass (C) or to the animal itself (C). "I'd like some chicken" refers to the meat. "I'd like some chickens" refers to the birds. How else are you going to describe the difference in grammar without using the terms "count(able)" and "non-count / uncountable / mass noun"? And if "chicken" doesn't denote an *entity*, what does? Not my downvote!

Comment: @Mari-LouA The noun "chicken" denotes a class of domestic fowl, dead or alive. When you say "I'd like some chickens" to refer to the particular type of fowl, dead or alive, you're using the plural form "chickens", which isn't a noun per se (because it doesn't denote a class of domestic fowl anymore) but is an NP with or without "some", and this NP "(some) chickens" denotes a plurality of entities. When you say "I'd like some chicken" to refer to the meat, "chicken" is a metonym.

Comment: `"chicken" is a metonym` I would have said it was a short for *chicken meat* not that it symbolises or represents "the edible cooked flesh of chickens" . This is the first time I've seen metonym used like that. Again, not my DV.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There's a first time for everything. [This wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) says: "The concept of metonymy also informs the nature of polysemy, i.e., how the same phonological form (word) has different semantic mappings (meanings). If the two meanings are unrelated, as in the word pen meaning both writing instrument and enclosure, they are considered homonyms. Within logical polysemies, a large class of mappings may be considered to be a case of metonymic transfer (e.g., "chicken" for the bird, as well as its meat; "crown" for the object, as well as the institution)."

Comment: Oh, in that way. I suppose so but I'm used to "Washington" meaning the US Gov't or the President, and Whitehall meaning the British Civil Service etc. Then even the names of vegetables and fruit would be metonyms: peach (the fruit, its pulp, the flavour) potato (the plant, the vegetable, the flesh etc.).

Comment: @Mari-LouA The whole metonym thing is a red herring, though. Metonym or not, the noun "chicken" in "I'd like some chicken" refers to a class of meat (a chicken meat as opposed to other classes of meat). It's the NP 'some chicken' or even the NP 'chicken' (in "I'd like chicken".) that denotes a concrete substance.

Comment: I'd modify the title if I were you, it's creating a bit of unnecessary ballyhoo, and once it reaches -5 (or -6) it no longer appears on the (active) home page.

Comment: I'm sticking with what I said in my first comment, that a *count noun* is a noun referring to a class of entities that can be counted. The idea that it isn't the noun itself being counted but the entity referred to by a noun phrase does not seem like a useful distinction to me, especially given that it is the noun itself that takes plural or singular form.

Comment: @nnnnnn Finally, someone who logically tries to argue. Then, here's my question for you. Do you believe that a plural form with -(e)s inflection can ever be considered to denote a class? If not, how could you be so sure that the plural form is a noun just as the singular form is?

Comment: Regarding your comment about the downvoters, I don't think it's helpful to label them cowards or to assume they don't understand what you're talking about. One of the official possible reasons for downvoting is that a question is "not useful", which is a matter of opinion. There is no requirement to provide an explanation along with a downvote, though with a question like yours that clearly has research and thought behind it I think it is only polite to do so. (Incidentally, I myself did not downvote, in case you wondered.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Another more plausible reason is to indicate "I don't know the answer," "beats me," or "OTT".

Answer (score 1):

> In [2], however, it is not the count noun ***plate*** itself but the whole noun phrase *another* **plate** that denotes an "entity"

and

> When a common noun denotes a "class", how can a common noun denote an "entity", let alone "an entity that can be counted or that cannot be counted"?

Q. *What do you like eating?*

A. ***Sandwiches***.

Doesn't the answer, *sandwiches*, in its isolation, prove it is a ***countable*** plural noun and denotes an entity? The number of sandwiches is unspecified but the speaker is referring to **more** than ***one sandwich***.

Q. *What do you like eating?*

A. ***Peanut butter***.

Why didn't I add the -s suffix? Because in grammar, this type of noun is labeled  *uncountable*, we cannot physically count something that is spread with **a knife**.

Comment: No: it's the noun "plate" that denotes the entity. The primary purpose of the determiner is to mark the noun as definite or indefinite.

Comment: @BillJ are we agreeing? I'm saying that sandwich and peanut butter are names for entities. I deliberately omitted a determiner. Maybe, I'm missing something here.