# What kind of noun is the word 'Luggage'?

Tags: nouns, collective-nouns, abstract-nouns

I was wondering what kind of noun is the word 'luggage'? I understand that it can neither be a proper noun nor a material noun. I also understand that it is an uncountable noun. But I'm rather interested in its place in  most elementary classification.  I consider the remaining three possibilities-

1. common noun
2. collective noun
3. abstract noun

Could anyone please answer this?

Comment: A mass/uncountable  noun; to refer to a single piece (bag, suitcase etc.) you would say “a piece of luggage”. Also, mainly AmE, baggage.

Comment: I know it is an uncountable noun, but could you specify its type?

Comment: The question forgets to say that "luggage" is an uncountable noun. That was my immediate response when I first read it.

Comment: Do you understand what an "abstract noun" means? Have you looked up the definitions of the different types of noun?

Comment: An abstract noun is one which is only conceptual, and can't be seen or felt, like name of emotions, feeling etcetera. I'm sorry if it isn't right. Actually, I have been learning English as a second language from my childhood. The above definition is what my instructor told me.

Comment: Thanks Mari-Lou A, I've edited the question.

Comment: To notify a user you need to preface the username with @  for example, @userXYZ.  As you are the author, you will always be notified if someone adds a comment to your post. I'm just saying this as I didn't  know you had replied but I came back to revisit the post

Comment: Related: [Is there a more specific name for uncount nouns such as: ‘furniture’, ‘equipment’, ‘luggage’, etc.?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421218/is-there-a-more-specific-name-for-uncount-nouns-such-as-furniture-equipment)

Comment: "Luggage" is a non-count common noun.

Comment: Even I won't argue that 'luggage' can be considered to have been countified, so 'non-count noun' works for once. / It is a common noun rather than a proper noun. / It refers to etically countable items. These items are obviously perceivable, so some would use 'concrete' here, but the abstract-concrete dichotomy is, if I remember rightly, binned as a hypothesis by most pycholinguists nowadays. / We don't speak of 'a baggage of suitcases, etc' so 'baggage' isn't a collective noun. //// You ...

Comment: seem to be under the misapprehension that nouns are uniquely classifiable into well-ordered subsets on which all linguists agree.

Comment: Following up on the last sentence of Mr. Ashworth's comment, classifications normally serve some purpose, and are applied in the light of that purpose. What depends on how you classify this particular word?